# How to access files from /tmp folder in google cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-storage

I followed the guide here:
http://gunargessner.com/gcloud-env-vars/

After reading the comment http://gunargessner.com/gcloud-env-vars/#comment-4061927247, I also placed the `.env` file in `/tmp`.

I would like to know how to set the contents of file `/tmp/.env` to environment so that my app can access it from `process.env.<varname>`

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage')
const storage = new Storage()
const bucketName = 'env-var'
await storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file('.env')
  .download({ destination: '/tmp/.env' })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('env downloaded')
    afterEnvProcess()
  })
```

How do I now set the `.env` file to `dotenv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on your app language but you can search for a `dotenv` lib on github.

For example:

- https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme (JS)
- https://github.com/joho/godotenv (GO)
- https://github.com/symfony/dotenv (PHP)

So when the app is started, you retrieve the `.env` file from the fileStorage service (i.e Google Cloud Storage) to `/tmp` (for AppEngine case). Then you can use the `dotenv` lib to parse the `.env` file en set the env vars.

Comment: Could you tell me how to access the /tmp/.env file?

Comment: As said above,  the dotenv library allows you to do that :) for example if you take a look at the dotenv JS doc you will find this : `require('dotenv').config({ path: '/full/custom/path/to/your/.env' })`

Comment: sorry, it seems i have been unable to convey my question correctly. When I said 'access', I meant to ask how to find the path to the .env file

Comment: **you** download the `.env` file **from** a Google Cloud Storage **to** `/tmp`.

Comment: So it means that, for each environment, you have a storage where you have a `.env` file in which the env var values are properly set to match `production`, `qualif`, `whatever_environment_you_want`.

Comment: For AppEngine it HAS to be `/tmp` or whatever **in_memory path** as you can't write on filesystem.

https://gist.github.com/rmasclef/6c52a0314694064ede7e6845a5f98287

keep in mind that this is an example here :)

Comment: I think you need this line : https://gist.github.com/rmasclef/6c52a0314694064ede7e6845a5f98287#file-getenv-js-L39 am I right ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the example. Yes, you are right. I will quickly try that out,